# Select list item by class name from div

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have had a search and I'm still a bit puzzled.

I am trying to select a list element by class name from a div using mootools.

The html is

```
<div class="someDiv">
  <ul class="aList">
    <li class="listItem0">
      <a href="#" class="nameVaries">
      </a>
  </li>
    <li class="listItem1">
      <a href="#" class="nameVaries">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div
```

I have tried using `check = $(event.target)getElement('a').getProperty('class');` and sending check to the console to check what I have but it is a null value.  I'm needing pointed in the right direction.  I'm pretty sure I need to select the div from the dom and then check the child elements for the class name and compare that to a value and then I can continue with whatever action I'd like.

Comment: Your HTML is malformed. The opening tag of each anchor element is missing a closing angle bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit unclear what you are trying to do, but please comment if I guess wrong.

You just missed a dot in your code. To get the class of the `a` element when you click the `someDiv` element you can use:

```
document.getElements('div.someDiv').addEvent('click', function () {
    var check = $(event.target).getElement('a').getProperty('class');
    console.log(check);
});
```

You can also use `var check = this.getElement('a').getProperty('class');`

Demo [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/A9RwG/1/)

EDIT (after your comment):

Ok, from your comment I think what you want is to listen to the `click` on the `a` element. It might be good to also prevent the link redirect from happening if you have code to run. So try this:

```
document.getElements('a').addEvent('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var check_this = this.getProperty('class');
    console.log(check_this);
});
```

You can then do the redirect with `window.location.href = this.getProperty('href');` when you are done with the code you need to run.

Check the **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NmgNa/)** for example with links with url.

Comment: That is kinda what I was looking for. Using your fiddle as a guide, the way I read about the event delegation meant it has to begin in the parent div so I may be unclear on what I am looking for. I essential want that layout but the click on the "some text" part to fire an event which checks against the "class name".  

So would I need to set the event on the 'a' and not the parent div?

Comment: @aldo, did you check my updated answer? was that what you were looking for?

Comment: @aldo, sure. You can post a new question. I am here some hours more (and many others I see, so you will get answers). Will look for it under the mootools tag

Comment: @aldo, why did you delete the question? Have you tried `$('dest' + my.slides.length)` I was preparing a demo for you...

Comment: Sorry, @Sergio I realised I was being an idiot... I'm just beginning to use mootools so no doubt will be back with more questions for you! I appreciate the help.

Comment: @aldo, I don't think you are an idiot. Yes, do come back with more Mootools questions :)